jOOQ codegen: Is there a way to read parquet files using DuckDB dialect?
As the title says, is there a workaround with jOOQ that would let me use DuckDB to query parquet files stored in object storage?
Example: read_parquet(s3://path/to/my/parquet_file)
I have a schema of the parquet files that I have defined in a script to generate jOOQ classes from.
I can think of one way that would be to avoid using jooq-codegen and do it all manually by defining constants, record mappers and query builders.
Is there a better way to do it using the auto generated classes?

Using views
jOOQ doesn't know anything about these dynamic external tables, out of the box. But you perhaps create a view that reads from the parquet file and query that view, instead, assuming DuckDB can discover the parquet meta data when describing the view to jOOQ using its INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.
Using schema mapping
Another approach would be to create a dummy table (or view) that describes the parquet file and then use runtime schema mapping to map from the dummy table to your function call. Make sure you turn off quoting of identifiers when doing this, otherwise, the whole function call is going to be quoted.
You could also use a VisitListener or model API replacement to replace the dummy table by the function call. That would be a bit more robust, as it wouldn't require turning off quoting of identifiers.
The dummy table doesn't even have to exist in your schema. You could define a second code generation run that uses the DDLDatabase just for this:
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase</name>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <key>sql</key>
          <value>create table dummy (col1 int, col2 int);</value>
        </property>
      </properties>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>

Plain SQL templating
Of course, code generation is really useful with jOOQ, but if all else fails, plain SQL templating is a pragmatic solution here. You can still combine this approach with the above dummy table, if you alias your plain SQL template to your dummy table.

Thank you for your response. Based on your response, the only options that were feasible for me were using VisitListener or runtime schema mapping. I tried the VisitListener method, but unfortunately, it fails when I join multiple tables. It overwrites the query for every joined table and the end result is read_parquet(s3://bucket-name/<LAST_JOINED_TABLE>.parquet). It also replaces table name in the join keys that are referred as tableName.Field in the query.

In the VisitListener, I simply check if the query part is an instance of Table class and then proceed to rewrite it (recursively in case it is an instance of QOM.JoinTable)

@HumaidKidwai: Just instanceof Table isn't enough, obviously. You have to check somehow, if the table is your table, not any table. Perhaps, ask a new question with all the details? (The comments section here isn't really good for such discussions...)

Perfect, all I had to do was to check if the table.getClass() is from any of the DefaultSchema.getTables() table classes and it worked!

Supposedly, jOOQ 3.19 supports DuckDB:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/supported-rdbms/
This should imply that the only other bits you'd need would be the DuckDB httpfs extension and of course the necessary permissions.
See https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/network_cloud_storage/s3_import.html for details, but in brief:
import httpfs; -- need only be done once (per user per machine)
load https;
# set up the credentials and S3 region to read data
SELECT * FROM read_parquet('s3://⟨bucket⟩/⟨file⟩');


Thanks for your response, but I don't think that you understood my question. I'm looking for a way to do it via jOOQ (specifically when I have auto generated table classes) . I know that this is the way to do it in DuckDB directly
